# Type of f g x = g . g x

Tags: haskell

It is not clear to me why the function defined as

```
f g x = g . g x
```

has the type

```
f :: (b -> a -> b) -> b -> a -> a -> b
```

I would have thought it would be of type

```
f :: (t -> t) -> t -> t
```

Can anyone explain to me how the expression is broken down? Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Note that function application has the highest priority; operators come later.

So, the term `g . g x` first applies `g` to `x`, and then composes the result and `g` itself. If `x` has type `b`, `g` must have type `b -> c`. Since we compose `g` with `g x` (the latter of type `c`), `c` must be a function type returning `b`, so `c = a -> b`. Now, the type of `g` is `b -> a -> b` and the type of `g . g x` is `a -> (a -> b)`; the type of `f` happens to be `(b -> a -> b) -> b -> a -> a -> b`.

If you wanted something like `(a -> a) -> a -> a` instead, you could try one of this

```
f g x = g (g x)
f g x = (g . g) x
f g x = g . g $ x
f g = g . g
```

Comment: So I get that g is of type (b -> a -> b) but then how do I infer the type of g . g x?

Comment: @SendMeMemes check out the signature of composition operator `(y -> z) -> (x -> y) -> x -> z` and match it with the types of its arguments: `g` and `g x`.

Answer (score 2):

The idea is about understanding the `(.)` operator, it has a type of

```
(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
```

It takes two functions each with *one* parameter and compose them, after applying `g x` the compiler assumed `g` is actually `g :: a -> b -> c` in order to satisfy the signature of `(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c` which takes two functions with one argument. Otherwise the code won't compile.

And finally if you want the signature `f :: (t -> t) -> t -> t` you need something like this:

```
λ> let applyTwice g = g.g
λ> :t applyTwice
applyTwice :: (a -> a) -> a -> a
λ> applyTwice (*2) 3
12
```